# I can't restore my backup with DriveImage XML

Tags: backup, restore, xml

Yesterday, I made a backup of my partition with the program DriveImage XML. After I made the backup, a message showed up. The message was `error of xml file` but I don't remember the details. I then pressed the OK button and a successful message appeared. After that, I went to restore my partition, but it said `restore failed`. I attached the xml file of the backup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<driveimage creator="DriveImage XML - Private Edition" version="Version 2.44" time="2014-05-22T15:22:50.984Z" destpath="D:\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\[BACKUP]\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\" filename="Drive_D" compressed="FALSE" compressionengine="0" raw="FALSE" split="FALSE" password="FALSE" id="807623757">

<drive>

<driveletter>G:</driveletter>

<drivelabel></drivelabel>

<totalspace>371788255232</totalspace>

<freespace>38036475904</freespace>

<usedlock>L</usedlock>

<shadowname></shadowname>

<filesystem>NTFS</filesystem>

<bootsector>61KQTlRGUyAgICAAAggAAAAAAAAA+AAAPwD/AOAo8A4AAAAAgACAAE0nSCsAAAAA2dJ7AQAAAADSCgAAAAAAAPYAAAABAAAAjauObsOOboYAAAA  A+jPAjtC8AHz7aMAHHx5oZgDLiBYOAGaBPgMATlRGU3UVtEG7qlXNE3IMgftVqnUG98EBAHUD6d  0AHoPsGGgaALRIihYOAIv0Fh/NE5+DxBieWB9y4TsGCwB126MPAMEuDwAEHloz27kAICvIZv8GEQADFg8AjsL/BhYA6EsAK8h377gAu80aZiPAdS1mgftUQ1BBdSSB+QIBch4WaAe7FmhSERZoCQBmU2ZTZlUWFhZ  ouAFmYQ4HzRozwL8KE7n2DPzzqun+AZCQZmAeBmahEQBmAwYcAB5maAAAAABmUAZTaAEAaBAAtE  KKFg4AFh+L9M0TZllbWmZZZlkfD4IWAGb/BhEAAxYPAI7C/w4WAHW8Bx9mYcOh9gHoCQCh+gHoAwD06/2L8Kw8AHQJtA67BwDNEOvyww0KQSBkaXNrIHJlYWQgZXJyb3Igb2NjdXJyZWQADQpCT09UTUdSI  GlzIGNvbXByZXNzZWQADQpQcmVzcyBDdHJsK0FsdCtEZWwgdG8gcmVzdGFydA0KAAAAAAAAAAAA  AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIoBpwG/AQAAVao=</bootsector>

<physicaldrive>DISK0</physicaldrive>

<physicalpartition>3</physicalpartition>

<physicaloffset>250620128</physicaloffset>

<physicalsectors>726148943</physicalsectors>

<physicalcapacity>976773168</physicalcapacity>

<physicalidename></physicalidename>

<clustersize>8</clustersize>

<bitmap><bitmapcount>113</bitmapcount>

<bitmapitem>0,7720715</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>7720733,1</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>7720767,945123</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>8666018,3740811</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>12406846,1</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>12406848,3</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>12406852,3</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>12406863,3</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>12406867,7</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>12406875,2</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>12406878,1</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>12406884,1</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>12406890,15379669</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>27786687,21528</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>27808343,655804</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>28464275,167294</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>28631697,128569</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>28760394,2742771</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>31504381,991800</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>32496309,236341</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>32809062,1203481</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>34218317,301056</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>34626789,649754</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>35394699,27283</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>35421983,5707</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>35427818,24819</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>35452765,82948</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>35616079,2032974</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>37649181,769243</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>38524498,663124</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>39187750,4456</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>39192334,15934</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>39208396,3654</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>39212178,5262</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>39217568,38533</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>39361303,694231</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>40055662,807067</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>40862857,11164</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>40874149,526595</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>41522294,202977</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>41725399,1640968</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>43366495,319151</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>43872781,462474</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>44386464,546019</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>44932611,3894</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>44936633,31495</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>44968256,10983</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>44979367,12619</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>44992114,12180</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>45004422,411871</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>45416421,4767</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>45421316,4436</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>45425880,1594145</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>47020153,364810</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>47385091,376879</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>47762098,1820481</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>49763479,1159622</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>50923229,210559</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>51133789,1</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>51133793,2</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>51133798,13</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>51133813,3</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>51133818,2</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>51133827,3</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>51133883,2233013</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>53473587,1135559</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>54609274,179185</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>54788587,5596</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>54794311,4081</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>54798520,3950</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>54802598,2512</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>54805238,4795</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>54810161,5177</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>54815466,31585</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>55372537,269956</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>55830540,37868</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>55944024,847198</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>56791350,7222</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>56798700,1542977</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>58341679,391695</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>58733502,14981</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>58748611,751863</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>59500602,2216</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>59502946,3603</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>59506677,8872</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>59515677,7468</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>59523273,592273</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>60115674,3254666</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>63626340,23967</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>63650435,9150</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>63659713,7625</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>63667466,301852</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>63969319,40959</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>64010279,135167</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>64145447,419853</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>64565428,148186</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>64713615,228175</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>64941791,2519114</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>67718616,2066995</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>71741035,2245828</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>73986991,294291</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>74467199,221646</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>74688973,1344813</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>76175404,2675590</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>78928587,73373</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>79002088,1</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>79002345,1</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>79007402,8384</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>79022867,1047299</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>80070294,599090</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>80669512,567481</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>81380149,366922</bitmapitem>

<bitmapitem>81747199,5006305</bitmapitem>

</bitmap>

<overhead>0,0</overhead>

<filetree rootname="\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\?\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\G:">

</filetree></drive></driveimage>
```